# Is there any way to store integer values dynamically in a dataset as INT64, INT16 or etc?

Tags: python, memory, memory-optimization

I am trying to optimize memory usage of my python program owing to my limited memory in a server. Following coding optimization, I am doing memory optimization. Input dataset is rather big. For this, I am investigating whether I can optimize the integer columns in the input dataset I use during the program. These integer values are dynamically changing in it. It means that there are sometimes mostly in the range of INT64 value ranges or in the range of INT32 or INT16. Is there any way to store these integer values dynamically in a dataset as INT64, INT16 or etc while I run the program?

I investigated any possibility to store dataset's integer columns dynamically but I couldn't find any way so far.

Comment: Can you clarify, ideally, using code, the structure of your dataset? Is it a numpy array? A list of ints? A pandas dataframe? something else?

Comment: @YakovDan it is a pandas dataframe.

Comment: Are you looking to for `astype` / `dtype`?

Comment: @JonSG I am looking to manage the input values dynamically for INT types rather than as all.

Comment: @fakedad Data comes from multiple databases through OracleSQL. Then I process the data from pandas dataframe. What do you suggest by SQLite here?

Comment: Have you checked out pandas dtype and astype as a possible path forward?